# Prove that $(a) n < k^+$ iff $n ≤ k$ and $(b) <$ is a transitive relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wonder if you could check my approach to this question? I am particularly unsure about part (b); it seems like it needs to be shown in a more substantial way. Thank you.

Question: We define the "less than" relation on the natural numbers by $a < b$ iff $a ∈ b$. Prove that

$(a) n < k^+$ iff $n ≤ k$.

$(b) <$ is a transitive relation.

My approach for $(a)$:

(i) Suppose $n = 1$ and $k = 0$. Then
 $n = 0^+ = \{∅\}$ and $k = 0 = ∅$ (Von Neumann ordinals)

(ii) If we want to say $n < k^+$, we want to say that $n ∈ k^+$, which is the same as $n ∈ (k ∪ \{k\}) <$-- (by the Successor function)

(iii) So, in this instance, $n < k^+$ would give us 
$\{∅\} ∈ (∅ ∪ \{∅\} )$
which is the same as 
$\{∅\} ∈ ∅$, which is false.

My approach for (b):

(i) Suppose this time that $n = 0$ and $k = 0$. Then
  $n = 0 = ∅$ and $k = 0 = ∅$

(ii) Therefore $n < k^+$ means 
$0 < 0^+$, or $0 < 1$
i.e.
$∅ < (∅ ∪ \{∅\})$ which is the same as
$∅ ∈ (∅ ∪ \{∅\})$ which is the same as
$∅ ∈ ∅$

Given that $a < b$ iff $a ∈ b$, then if $<$ is a transitive relation, what is implied is 
$A ∈ B → A ⊆ B$

(From (ii) above) $∅⊆∅$ (trivially true)

Therefore $<$ is a transitive relation.

Answer (score 0):

Your (iii) for (a) is incorrect: you should get $\{\varnothing\in\{\varnothing\}\cup\{\varnothing\}\}$, which is true, not $\{\varnothing\}\in(\varnothing\cup\{\varnothing\})$, which is false. (However, $\varnothing\cup\{\varnothing\}$ is $\{\varnothing\}$, not $\varnothing$.)

To show that $n<k^+$ iff $n\le k$, assume first that $n<k^+$. This means that $n\in k^+$, and since $k^+=k\cup\{k\}$, this means that $n\in k\cup\{k\}$. Thus, either $n\in k$, in which case $n<k$, or $n\in\{k\}$, in which case $n=k$, and it follows that $n\le k$. Conversely, if $n\le k$, then either $n<k$, in which case $n\in k$, or $n=k$, in which case $n\in\{k\}$, and in either case $n\in k\cup\{k\}=k^+$. Note that no induction is required.

I can’t make head or tail of your argument for (b), I’m afraid; as written it simply makes no sense. You should be trying to show that if $n<k$ and $k<m$, then $n<m$, i.e., that if $n\in k$ and $k\in m$, then $n\in m$. It you’ve already shown that von Neumann ordinals are transitive sets with respect to the relation $\in$, this is immediate. If not, then you have a fair bit of work to do.

Comment: Thankyou very much - much needed clarity there. With regard to (iii), it was {∅} ∈ {∅ ∪ {∅}) (rather than {∅} ∈ {∅, {∅}}) - am I still very lost in my beginner's amblings, or is the union of ∅ and {∅} equal to ∅? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Stumpedphilosopher: You’re welcome. I’ve corrected the first paragraph so that it matches what you wrote, with the parentheses. No, $\varnothing\cup\{\varnothing\}=\{\varnothing\}$: the members of $\varnothing\cup\{\varnothing\}$ are the things that are in $\varnothing$ together with the things that are in $\{\varnothing\}$. There’s nothing in $\varnothing$, and the one thing in $\{\varnothing\}$ is $\varnothing$, so the one thing in $\varnothing\cup\{\varnothing\}$ is $\varnothing$; i.e., $\varnothing\cup\{\varnothing\}=\{\varnothing\}$.